# 425 Security: Bad IP connecting when trying to connect to ftp server behind load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, ftp, tcp

I have an ec2 instance with vsftp installed. The daemon is listening on port 21:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1730/vsftpd
```

I am able to ftp and upload files through filezilla when connecting to the instance IP address itself. However, when I add the instance to a classic load balancer and try to connect to the load balancer, I get the following error:

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (3,23,102,171,4,6).
Command:    LIST
Response:   425 Security: Bad IP connecting.
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

The only options I changed in the vsftpd.config are the following:

```
listen=YES
# listen_ipv6=YES
write_enable=YES

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=3.23.102.171
```

All the other options are the defaults. There is nothing else installed on the server and clearly the Security Groups allow access.

What's this error about and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I don't think FTP is compatible with load balancing. It's a truly ancient protocol that does some bizarre things we would not think of doing today, because they wouldn't work well (or at all) with firewalls, load balancers, proxies, IPv6, etc. If possible, you should migrate away from FTP.

Comment: `PASV` mode directs the client to another port, in your case in the range 1024-1048.  The load balancer will also need to forward these ports to the backend.

Comment: I think you can solve it via your firewall.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have tackled almost everything. But some small things might be missing.

To run vsftpd behind a load balancer you need to:

### Enable passive mode and set ports:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
```

Obviously these **ports needs to be exposed** on your load balancer.

### Setup a pasv_address and connect to it:

You should setup a `pasv_address`, just like you did. But make sure:

1. You are connecting with this address on your ftp clinet: `ftp same-address-as-config`
2. If **your address is a name, add `pasv_addr_resolve=YES`**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got same kind of error and it just got simply fixed by restarting the vsftpd.

I was working on RHEL 6 serever. so I used the below command

```
service vsftpd restart
```

Then I tried sending the files through ftp and it was working perfectly fine.

I am not sure if it helps the above issue but its worth giving a try.